# How can I solve this median programming problem in C++

Tags: c++

1. Formulate the steps of identifying the median from five unique numbers and visualize them in flow chart.
2. Develop an application that shows the median after getting five unique numbers from users.
3. Extend the feature for allowing six unique numbers input and computing the median.

Example:
Input: `5 4 2 1 10`
Output: `Median = 4`

I found this question in a [Problem Solving with C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321531345) by [Walter Savitch](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=ntt_athr_dp_sr_1?_encoding=UTF8&sort=relevancerank&search-alias=books&field-author=Walter%20Savitch) but I couldn't solve it. Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: By book do you mean textbook? And by found do you mean "assigned to me by a teacher"?

Comment: and array pointers, functions, standard template library (STL) are not allowed

Comment: u can find the book walter savinch solve C++
this is the name of the book

Comment: What you need to do is post how far you've got - why not start with step 1, and consider how you'd explain to someone how a median is calculated...

Comment: I think it means draw out what the program flow would be.  Not actually code something to do that.

Comment: if you search for "median" on Google or Wikipedia you will find useful pointers to Q1 in the first 2-3 hits. On SO you will get help when you show you have tried to answer at least some of the question

Comment: I just wrote this in basic for a Ti-83 for my stat class one day when really bored haha. It should be pretty easy to implement in C++, you should probably continue to read up on your C++ and use this as a practice exercise instead of just getting the answer here. IMHO of course.

Comment: This is so much easier to do if you can use arrays or linked lists, but then part of the point may be to understand why collections can be a good thing.

Comment: You could try and change the question a bit. "I need help in c++" is not very helpful. How about "How to find the median of an array in C++"?

Comment: There's really no *programming* question here.  "Develop an application" doesn't count as a programming question.

Comment: Is that the book you were talking about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trying to give homework-friendly advice:

1) [Make sure you know how to get a Median](http://easycalculation.com/statistics/learn-median.php).  Can you, in your head or on paper, figure it out?  Now, how do you write a program to do this for you?  [Make a flowchart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart).

2) Write the program to do it.  A user gives your program 5 numbers, your program gives the median as an answer.

3) Make the program better. An even amount of numbers changes the method to get a median.  Change your program so that it will allow 6 numbers.

3b)  Make your program accept any amount of numbers.  (I added this, not in your post or in your book but should be super-easy to do if you've already done 2 and 3).

Comment: Agreed on 3b. The book should have asked this instead.

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone explain it to me?

1. "Formulate the steps" means, "explain how to do it". For example, imagine that you're explaining to me how to solve the problem, that I don't need to use a computer (that I'm trying to do it with pencil and paper), and that I don't know what a "median" is.
2. "Develop an application" means, "write software". The software will need to: a) get five numbers from the user (and, possibly, ensure that the numbers are "unique"); b) find the "median" (using the steps you've previously formulated in step 1); c) show (output) the median which it found.
3. You'll need to define what "median" means when there's an even number of inputs, and alter your program accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I know no one asked for an answer using STL, but it could be useful for someone coming here later.

In C++ with STL there is a function called `nth_element`, which takes three arguments. It will sort a container just enough to get nth element in the right spot.

An example:

```
int numbers[] = { 5, 4, 2, 1, 10 };
std::nth_element(numbers, numbers+2, numbers+5);
std::cout << numbers[2] << "\n";
```

Comment: Probably too complex for a beginner.

Comment: But not for the advanced beginner who will stumble by in a few weeks :)

Comment: Well,the OP didn't allowed STL.

Comment: Without going to meta: it's not only about the OP. It's also about learning from each other. If your looking for a solution to this problem, my solution will work.

Comment: Go on then, +1. It doesn't answer the question, but the question will appear in search results. Maybe some poor soul who wants to know is going to be tricked by the question name into thinking that this question is a good place to get information about finding a median in C++. Might as well not waste their time.